# Why can't show restaurant list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to make some restaurant list.
I associated two tables, and then write this code.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :restaurant_translations
end

class RestaurantTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'restaurant_translations'
end
```

restaurant_controller.rb

```
class RestaurantController < ApplicationController
        def list
                @restaurants = Restaurant.all
logger.debug @restaurants
        end
end
```

list.html.slim
    table
      thead
        tr
          th Type
          th Name
          th Url
          th Genre
          th Addr

```
  tbody
    - @restaurants.each do |restaurant|
      tr
        td = restaurant.restaurant_type
        td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.restaurantname
        td = link_to 'here', restaurant.url
        td = restaurant.genre
        td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.address
```

But results are belows.
"undefined method `restaurantname' for #"

[image]

How can I do this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: restaurantname  field in which table restaurant_translations or restaurant

Comment: restaurantname is belonged to restaurant_translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your restauration have multiple 'restaurant_translations'.

Example, for first you can write `td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.try(:restaurantname)`

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.restaurantname
```

with

```
td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.restaurantname
```

this will help you

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful.

Comment: if its helpful please upvote the answer & accept it  :- )

Answer (score -1):

because Restaurent has_many :restaurant_translations
so you need to loop through

```
restaurant.restaurant_translations.each do|res_trans|
your code here
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe is it necessary to make inside loop?

Comment: if you want to show all restaurent_translations loop is necessary